# Interference with multiple beams

Tags: optics, interference

In "Interference with multiple beams" from the book "Introduction to Modern Optics" the geometric path difference between any two successive transmitted rays is $2d \cos \theta$. The corresponding phase difference is $2kd \cos \theta$. How and why $k$ (called wave vector) is there in the equation?

Comment: Your question needs clarification.  What does "any two successive transmitted rays" mean?   In any event $k=2\pi/\lambda$.   $kd$ makes the phase go from $0$ to $2\pi$ as distance goes from $0$ to $\lambda$.   Or $n\lambda$ to $(n+1)\lambda$

Comment: Voting to re-open. The question is clear and specific. The answer (as stated in previous comment) is that the factor of $k=\frac {2 \pi}{\lambda}$ is required to convert a distance (path difference) into a phase.

Answer (score 1):

The path difference $2d \cos \theta$ has dimensions of length. To convert the path difference into a phase difference - which is dimensionless - we must multiply it by a conversion factor with dimensions 1/length. If the phase difference is in radians then this conversion factor is $k = \frac {2 \pi} {\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the beam. If we want the phase difference in degrees then the conversion factor would be $\frac {360} {\lambda}$ instead.